# A total of $60$ (indistinguishable) iPads are to be distributed to $7$ elementary school classrooms. How many ways are there to do this if

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> A total of $60$ (indistinguishable) iPads are to be distributed to $7$ elementary school classrooms. How many ways are there to do this if

> (a) There are no restrictions?

> (b) Four of the classrooms receive iPads but three do not.

If the iPads were distinguishable then I could say that for (a) the answer would be $ = 60 \cdot 59 \cdot ... \cdot 54$ but I'm really losing it when it comes to indistinguishable objects.

I am  completely lost solving this. Can anyone help me understand the problem in a easier way so that I can solve it?

P.S. : I don't need full solution, just some help understanding it, hints at max so that I can solve it on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbf{\text{Note 2}}=$ I am sorry, i did not see that you do not want the answers , so i have erased them now , if you find the solution , you can write them to comment section , and i can check them for you.

a-) It is said that the ipads are identical and the classrooms are distinct , so by using stars and bars there are ... ways , because there is not anymore restriction.

Lets come to the logic behind this method assume that the ipads are represented by "*" and $|$ represents the classrooms.If there were $5$ identical ipads and $3$ different classrooms then ,one of the distribution will be "$**|*|**$" ,by using combinantion with repetition ,we find the all arrangements of stars and bars formula ,$C(m+n-1 ,n)$ where m is the number of distinct boxes (in this question it represents classrooms , to satisfy the number bars ,we subtract $1$ from $m$)  and $n$ is the number of stars, you can also think their arrangements as permutation with repetition , so it give use all arrangements.In that example , we applied it for $60$ stars and $6$ bars , we used $6$ bars because it gives us $7$ places to represent $7$ classrooms.

b-) Select $4$ classroom that take ipads by $C(7,4)$ and again stars and bars ... , then $$C(7,4) \times ..$$

For more information as to star and bars , look at : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

$\mathbf{\text{Note}}=$ If the ipads were distinct then , it would $\mathbf{\color{red}{\text{not}}}$ be equal to $60 \times 59 \times 58 ... 54$ as you said (if there is not restriction) , in that cases , you had better use exponential generating functions.

Comment: Thank you. I understand it now. I completely forgot this method. If you wouldn't have demonstrated it for the 5,3 example I wouldn't have gotten it.

Comment: @Itachi you are welcome :) ! I glad to help you

Comment: wouldn't in your final answer it'd be $C(m+n-1 ,m)$ since we are moving the bars only? Because at first you did that and I also thought it was logically correct.

Comment: @Itachi i said something missing there  , i will edit it. m is the number of distinct boxes , or in your question the classrooms, to turn them into bars , we write $m-1$ ,as a result $C(m+n-1,n)$ or $C(m+n-1,m-1)$ , they are equal

Comment: @Itachi we do not move only the bars , all of them moving , it is like how many arrangements are there by using the letters of $mississippi$